# Driverpack Solution makes a whole bunch of programs

Tags: drivers, uninstall, system-restore

I am using Driver Pack solution 12.3 to update my drivers. I used it and installed 55 drivers. I noticed that there are now several dozen new entries in add/remove programs under the name Windows Driver Package - Intel hdc, Windows Driver Package - Intel System, and Windows Driver Package - Intel USB with the driverpack solution logo next to them. When I hit uninstall for any of these, it says all devices using this driver will be removed, and I am scared of uninstalling anything I do not know about. I have no system restore points before I updated my driver. Will these extra driver packages slow down my computer or take up extra disk space? Can I uninstall them safely? I am using Windows 8, so refreshing the computer is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* use such rubbish programs to install drivers! Get all latest drivers from manufacturer sites only and manually install yourself. Spend some time and effort to avoid such complaints later. Extra useless drivers are not good. Remove all, then go to Device Manager and refresh to detect hardware and install proper drivers only. If not possible to clear all drivers, refresh or reset PC and learn a valuable lesson.

Comment: Will uninstalling the driver packages make the computer unusable? I mean, will I be able to do anything? Even be able to refresh the computer? What is the worst possible thing that can happen if I uninstall a driver package? Some of the drivers are for internal things in the computer I think, not just mice, keyboards, or other external devices.

Comment: When you installed Windows first time it had no extra drivers, right? Only default Windows drivers were there, and same will be used if you remove the new drivers. If some devices have no drivers, they will show ! in Device Manager. You can then install latest driver for them manually from their sites.

Comment: Are the installed components actually drivers? Or are they just called that way? (Do not download and run unknown programs from the Internet. Even if they have names like 'driverpackage.exe' or 'somesucductivegirlname_screensaver.scr.exe'

Comment: +1 for refresh.  Good chgance this system is now infected with something unwelcome.

Comment: I checked several reviews for Driver Pack Solution and they were mostly good, and my antivirus said it was OK.

Answer (score -1):

I have used driverpack for years now since before windows 7, and I have NEVER had a problem with this, and it finds drivers from the internet that are even more updated than some of the one's off of the site, too!!  It performs a Restore point before it changes Anything, and is a very handy program for finding missing drivers for your chipsets, because it actually reads the hardware registers and finds the Real drivers from it's database.  So if you don't use it, don't just automatically dismiss it, because you are ignorant of it.